# Overriding field.html.twig in my module

Tags: theming, 8

I'm writing a field formatter and I need to override the default field formatting. I've already implemented themes for the items itself, but I can't get my theme to work for the field container.

I've set #theme in the following code, and my field-image.html.twig is found by Drupal and processed:

```
class ImageGalleryFormatter extends ImageFormatter {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function viewElements(FieldItemListInterface $items) {
    $elements = parent::viewElements($items);
    foreach ($elements as &$element) {
      $element['#theme'] = 'imagegallery_format';
    }
    $elements['#theme'] = 'field_image';
    $elements['#attached']['library'][] = 'imagegallery_formatter/light-gallery';
    return $elements;
  }

}
```

But it doesn't actually work correctly, I don't get any content for {{ item.content }}. This is the core of my field-image.html.twig:

```
{% for item in items %}
   <div>{{ item.content }}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

I suspect that I didn't implement hook_theme() correctly, I tried a few variants, but none worked.

```
function imagegallery_formatter_theme() {
  return array(
    'imagegallery_format' => array(
      'variables' => array('item' => NULL, 'item_attributes' => NULL, 'url' => NULL, 'image_style' => NULL),
    ),
    'igimage' => array(
    'variables' => array(
        'style_name' => NULL,
        'uri' => NULL,
        'width' => NULL,
        'height' => NULL,
        'alt' => '',
        'title' => NULL,
        'attributes' => array(),
      ),),
      'field_image' => array(
        'render element' => 'element',),
  );
}
```

The first two themes work, for those I simply copied the variables array from existing code. The third one doesn't work, and I couldn't find any existing code I could use as a template. I tried to define the variables instead of using 'render element', but I don't know how to define the `items` variable there. I tried setting it to NULL or an empty array, but nothing did work. When I put a variables array in hook_theme, I get simply four empty divs, with the render element array I get a single empty div.

What am I doing wrong here, and how do I override this theme correctly in my module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to track down the place in core where the code for this specific theme is located, it was in `core/includes/theme.inc` and not in the field or system module where I previously searched. Copying from there did work in the end, using `render element` in hook_theme() is correct, but I was missing an important preprocess function.

I defined the following function and called the original preprocess function from there:

```
function template_preprocess_field_image(&$vars, $hook) {
    template_preprocess_field($vars, $hook);
}
```